# In Hive, can a beetle go up/down into an empty space?

Tags: hive

Consider a Beetle surrounded on 5 sides, thus there is a space in the ring around it.

Can the Beetle move from the centre of this arrangement, into the space?  A normal 'planar' move is prevented under these circumstances but a Beetle can move vertically.  It could climb on to a neighbour then down into the space in two moves; but can it do the move up-and-down into the space in one move?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a beetle is not climbing up onto or down off of a piece, it moves exactly like a Queen Bee. A beetle cannot move into a space it cannot physically slide into.

reference: http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Hive_FAQ#toc10

Comment: +1 That is completely not the answer I would have expected, but your reference clarifies the situation up very well.